# Get index names of a multi-dimensional array in PHP

Tags: php, arrays, regex, wordpress, indexing

I have a form with multiple input fields, which are serialized and passed to a function via AJAX. Inside the function, I have the data in below form. I need to get `Book-Keeper`, `publish-companies`, and `1` as separate variables.

```
// $key = '_data'
// $values = {"name":"_data[Book-Keeper][publish_companies]","value":"1"}
```

Here's the function code.

```
function fnc_edit_roles(WP_REST_Request $request) {

    $variables = $_REQUEST; 

    // Get all $_POST variables into $data[] array with key=>value
    if( $variables ) {

        while ( list( $field, $value ) = each( $_REQUEST )) {

            if( $field !== '_nonce' ) {
                $data[$field] = $value;
            }

        } // end while

    } // end if

    foreach( $data as $key=>$values ) {
        // $key = '_data'
        // $values = {"name":"_data[Book-Keeper][publish_companies]","value":"1"}
        // How do I get 'Book-Keeper', 'publish_companies', and '1' into separate variables?

    }

    $result = array( 'msg' => $data, 'error' => false );
    return json_encode( $result );

}
```

And here's how I get the inputs in HTML.

```
<form id="_user_roles_form" method="post" class="form-horizontal">
    <div class="form-group row">
        <label class="col-lg-6 control-label">Publish Companies</label>
        <div class="col-lg-6">
            <div class="btn-group" data-toggle="buttons">
                <label class="btn btn-default active">
                    <input type="radio" name="_data[Book-Keeper][publish_companies]" value="1"/> True
                </label>
                <label class="btn btn-default ">
                    <input type="radio" name="_data[Book-Keeper][publish_companies]" value="0"/> False
                </label>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</form>
```

And here's how I pass the inputted data to AJAX function.

```
var _data = jQuery('#_user_roles_form').serializeArray();

jQuery.ajax({
    url: myAjaxUrl,
    type: 'POST',
    data: _data,
    success: function( json ) {
        var result = JSON.parse( json );
        console.log( result.msg );
    }
});
```

Long question short, how do I get `Book-Keeper` and `publish_companies` out of the string `_data[Book-Keeper][publish_companies]`? `key` or `array_keys` doesn't work here...

Comment: @Donsgan can you share the array for getting indexes name?

Comment: @SahilGulati Array ( [Book-Keeper] => Array ( [publish_companies] => 1 ) ); This is what I get by print_r in PHP, which is later serialized and passed to AJAX in javascript.

Comment: ``do you want `Book-Keeper` and `publish_companies` both ? or just `Book-Keeper`?

Comment: Can you tell me this is the sample `// $key = '_data'
// $values = {"name":"_data[Book-Keeper][publish_companies]","value":"1"}`?

Comment: Say, I need `Book-Keeper` into $role_name, `publish_companies` into $cap_name. Yes, that is the actual sample I get inside the function to which the serialized array are passed. Right now I get them into separate variables using `str_replace` and `explode`, but I guess there's a proper way to handle this. Please shed some light on me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this hope this will help you out. Here we are using Regex: `\[([\w\-]+)\]` which will match Example: `[something-some_value]`

[**Try this code snippet here**](https://eval.in/780970)

```
ini_set('display_errors', 1);

foreach ($data as $key => $values)
{
    //$key = '_data';
    //$values = '{"name":"_data[Book-Keeper][publish_companies]","value":"1"}';
    $array = json_decode($values, true);
    $value = $array["value"];//will contain value
    preg_match_all("/\[([\w\-]+)\]/", $array["name"], $matches);
    list($role_name,$cap_name)=$matches[1];
    echo $role_name;//will contain role name
    echo $cap_name;//will contain company name
}
```

Comment: Thanks my genius friend.